# What does "No less ...than" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Today I read the paper of [Blondheim (2002)](https://academic.oup.com/jah/article/89/3/869/832555?login=true), they said:

> War is **no less** about mobilizing human minds and wills **than** about
> recruiting supplies, weapons, and manpower and deploying them in
> combat.

I am confusing what do they want to mention here, what is the comparison between "mobilizing human minds and wills" and "recruiting supplies, weapons, and manpower and deploying them in combat"

Comment: Suppose the sentence is simplified to "War is no less about intelligence than about logistics." It isn't really a comparison, but saying that both are necessary.

Comment: It's not common phrasing (because it's semantically confusing, even for some native speakers). Better would be *X is **as much** about Y **as it is** about Z* (the implication being that people tend to think X is all about Z, but speaker is pointing out that Y is ***at least as important*** as Z).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples off the top of my head to hopefully help clarify the issue:

*His fighting style is **no less** about resilient defending **than** (it is about) relentless attacks.* 
*His fighting style is **as much** about resilient defending **as** (it is about) relentless attacks.* 
*His success is **equally** about resilient defending **and** relentless attacks.*

*His success is **no less** due to hard work **than** (it is about) talent.* 
*His success is **as much** due to hard work **as** (it is about) talent.* 
*His success is **equally** due to hard work **and** talent.*

To sum up:

*It is **no less** about X **than** it is about Y.*
*It is **as much** about X **as** it is about Y.* 
*It is **equally** about X **and** Y.*